# Why am I unable to sign up to Linux server remotely?

Tags: 18.04, ssh

For over 5 hours now I've been having trouble logging into my Linux account remotely. I've used the ssh client, Putty, as well as my MAC terminal. I understand that in order to login, we must use **ssh username@hostname or IP address**. In my case, it is **ssh username@10.0.2.15** but in the end, I constantly receive the message **ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Operation timed out** Can someone please help me? I've even tried to disable sshd but that didn't work either.

Comment: A timeout on connection often indicates that a firewall is preventing access. When the port is allowed in the firewall but there is no service behind it, you get a "connection refused". You can still try to enable verbosity/debug in the ssh client with `ssh -vv username@10.0.2.15`. This may give more information.

Comment: you could also check the host is up (it's possibly down) and ports open with `nmap -PN 10.0.2.15`

Comment: So far opening the ports haven't worked with nmap -PN 10.0.2.15, so I will try to enable versoity/debug.

Answer (score -1):

Get on the command line as root 
Then cd to /etc/ssh and do the following

```
cd /etc/ssh
nano sshd_config       note that is an underscore in the file name
```

using nano you must uncomment the line

```
# PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

change it to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Restart SSH

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: I tired doing this and I am still unable to log in remotely.